# Git - How to ignore all files inside one directory recursively but some files with an specific extension

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm using `Windows 7`  with `Git v2.8.3`.

I have [this directory structure](https://filetea.me/t1sZIxfm0yaQZ68m97qw3jxTQ/dl?8484c8fe-6554-4472-80a6-2f413a760550) which contains a `Git` repository.

```
testing_gitignore
│   .gitignore
│   file_1.txt
│   file_2.txt
│
├───dir_1
│       file_11.txt
│       file_12.txt
│       file_13.txt
│
└───dir_2
    │   file_21.txt
    │   file_22.txt
    │   file_23.xlsx
    │   file_24.txt
    │
    └───dir_21
            file_211.txt
            file_212.xlsx
            file_213.txt
```

I wanna configure the `.gitignore` file in order to ignore all files inside `dir_2` recursively but keeping (for commit) the files with extension: `.xlsx` (recursively).

Inside `.gitignore` I used the following:

```
/dir_2/*
/dir_2/**/*
!/dir_2/*.xlsx
!/dir_2/**/*.xlsx
```

But I get no success because I get as files to `commit` the following list (which you can see also [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hKZp.png)):

```
.gitignore
file_1.txt
file_2.txt
dir_1\file_11.txt
dir_1\file_12.txt
dir_1\file_13.txt
dir_2\file_23.xlsx
```

but I expect it should be included (as file to commit) the file:

```
dir_2/dir_21/file_212.xlsx
```

Could you give me a `.gitignore` configuration to achieve this?
(before posting here could you try it by yourself with the directory structure I attached before for download on the link?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to ignore files but re-include folders:

```
/dir_2/**/*
!/dir_2/**/
```

(Note the `/**/*` of the first rule: it ignores all files and folders recursively, then re-include folders `!/**/` in the second rule).

Then you can re-include files (because their folders are not ignored)

```
!/dir_2/**/*.xlsx
```

The main rule about `.gitignore` remains:

[**It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309)

So ignoring files *and* folders (with '`/**/*`') means you won't be able re-include files unless their parent folders are themselves re-included (with `!/**/`: trailing slash means 'folders').
Full `.gitignore`:

```
/dir_2/**/*
!/dir_2/**/
!/dir_2/**/*.xlsx
```

Note that you don't have to commit a `.gitignore` to test its effect: modify it, and do a `git status`: as long as those files where not tracked (do a `git rm -r --cached dir_2` first), the effect of those rules will be immediate.

With that `.gitignore` in place, do a `git add .`, and a `git status`: it should only show `*.xlsx` under `dir_2/` as being added.

[ pay attention to the underscores ]

Comment: could you clarify more on this?. I tried your first 3 lines but didn't work. thanks

Comment: I tried your last 3 lines but still not working. I haven't make any `commit` yet (even no initial commit), so I think I don't need to do `git rm`.

Comment: @DavidSmith What `git status` returns? (also what is your `git version`?)

Comment: The `git status` returns what you can see on [this image](https://filetea.me/t1s2Lmd0yDVS8u2WxuECK3oxQ/dl). I'm using: `Windows 7` with `Git v2.8.3`

Comment: @DavidSmith OK: after testing, I have fixed the answer

Comment: ups, still not working, I get [this](https://filetea.me/t1s5MH5IaYCSES0AJBthYqSZw/dl). It includes what is strictly inside directory: `dir_2` but not in a recursive manner. What is inside directory: `/dir_2/dir_21/` is not included (I mean `.php` files).

Comment: I got a bit close now by doing: `/dir_2/**/*.*` and then `!/dir_2/**/*.xlsx` on the second line. But if I put a file with name: `other` (no extension) inside the directory: `/dir_2/dir_21/` then it will be included on the commit and it suppose not to be because it doesn't have the extension: `.xlsx`. Any idea on how to prevent that inclusion (in a correct way)?

Comment: @DavidSmith I have tested the `.gitignore`: it just works: you need to exclude files, then re-include folders. Trying to re-include files won't work fully. In other words, the second line *must* be `/dir_2/**/`.

Comment: @DavidSmith And try with https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.11.0-rc2.windows.1/PortableGit-prerelease-2.11.0.rc2.windows.1-64-bit.7z.exe  (it is an autro-extractible archive: no setup). Git 2.8.3 is ancient on Windows. Git 2.11 is more recent.

Comment: it is working now. You was right with your 3 lines of code above except one small typo I just fixed it. Your suggestion is working for me on Windows 7 /  Git v2.8.3 and CentOS v6.8 / Git v2.4.5. You saved my day, thanks a lot!